# Do i have to use "Spring Rabbit" instead of "Spring Cloud Stream"

Tags: java, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-stream

I'm working on a project which tries to adopt **messaging-driven** framework. (Different independent components communicate with the messages routed by message broker)

**RabbitMQ** was chosen as the Broker finally.

For the framework, at first we try to use **Spring Cloud Stream**, but when we try to leverage Rabbit characteristics, such as: **Exchange, routing key, alternate exchange...** We find it hard to use them in Spring Cloud Stream.

So my question is:

- Do i have to use **Spring Rabbit (or maybe Spring Integration)** instead of Spring Cloud Stream?
- Do you have any **suggestions/best practices** about them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Cloud Stream is very opinionated about queues, exchanges, routing keys; we are considering adding more flexibility in a future release but, for now, you can use Spring AMQP directly and it's not a lot different - `@RabbitListener` instead of `@StreamListener` for example. Whether or not you add Spring Integration as well really depends on what your application needs are.

Comment: A year later, is this answer still true? Hasn't it become more 'flexible'?

Comment: Yes; you can now provide your own infrastructure (queues, exchanges, bindings). See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties).